# findOneAndUpdate not returning original document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Environment**

```
node -v
v10.0.0
// native driver "mongodb": "^3.0.8",
```

**Desired Behavior**

I want to update a document and return the original document.

**Actual Behavior**

The updated document is being returned, instead of the original document.

**What I've Tried**

Initially I was looking at `findAndModify`:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findAndModify

however the docs there say that it is deprecated and to `use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead`.

So I tried:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {

        // find object in array of objects ('statements') and return the 'text' property value
        var old_text = result.value.statements.find(x => x.id === "my_great_id").text;

        console.log(old_text);

    }
});
```

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate

The docs say that the option `returnOriginal` is default, however it is logging the updated value, rather than the original value.

**Edit:**

The problem was elsewhere in code - the code above works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

By default `findOneAndUpdate` function returns the original document.
But adding `{new: false}` to the third parameter of `findOneAndUpdate` function may work in your case.

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {new: false}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    res.send(err);
  } else {

    // find object in array of objects ('statements') and return the 'text' property value
    var old_text = result.value.statements.find(x => x.id === "my_great_id").text;

    console.log(old_text);

}});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a bug elsewhere in code, fixed it and app worked as expected.